# Regular Expression Dynamic Format

Tags: php, regex, string, logic, expression

Can some one help me in checking a sting using regular expression:

My String will be in any format lets see

> 12AAA22TBI

The above Sting is in a format of `NNTTTNNTTT`

Where

> N - Number,
>         T - TEXT

I am able to write a code to check the format in static. But the format will come dynamic.

Suppose the second case might be `123456TTT = NNNNNNTTT`
The Format will be different. Can some one help me to write a regular express with dynamic value;

**Note:** The length of the string as well as the length of the FORMAT will Change.

Pseudo code:

```
Function ('FORMAT','STRING'){
IF(FORMAT == STRING): Return 1;
ELSE Return 0;
}
```

`FORMAT == STRING` Here I need help to check the Format and string using regular expression but dynamically.

Example:
My Function will be same but the Format and String will differ:

```
1. NNNTTTNN -- 111ABC22
2. TNTNTNTN -- A1B2C3D4
3. TTTTNNNNN -- ABCD12345
4. TTNNTTTTTT -- AB01ABCDEF
```

The above is some of the examples.

Comment: Are you asking "*how to convert `NNTTTNN` to a regex?*", or something else?

Comment: Yes,, But here the NNTTTNN will be dynamic,,, like TTTTNNNTT it may change the position but we need to check the format with respect to the format. in string..

Comment: Please add some examples - input and output

Comment: use str_replace to convert `N` to `\d` and `T` to `\a` or `\w`. Store the new string as pattern and match it against the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the example code below as a start...

```
$format = 'NNTTTNNTTT';
$value  = '12AAA22TBI';

$format = preg_replace('/[^NT]/', '', $format);
$format = preg_replace('/T/', '[A-Z]', $format);
$format = preg_replace('/N/', '\d', $format);
$format = "/^$format$/";

$match = (preg_match($format, $value));

print "$match\n";
```

Test it **[here](http://ideone.com/OxCcyp)**.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple function that generates a regex, you could simply add rules to support other characters and map them to a specific regex:

```
function generateRegex($input){
    $rules = array(
        'N' => '[0-9]',
        'T' => '[a-zA-Z]',
        // You could add more rules here
    );
    $delimiter = '~';

    $output = strtr($input, $rules); // Replace-Fu
    $output = '^' . $output . '$'; // Add begin and end anchor, comment this line out if you don't want it.
    $output = $delimiter . $output . $delimiter; // Add the delimiters
    return $output; // Should I explain o_O ?
}
```

A demo :

```
$inputArr = array('NNNTTTNN','TNTNTNTN','TTTTNNNNN','TTNNTTTTTT');
foreach($inputArr as $input){
    echo $input . '->' . generateRegex($input) . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
NNNTTTNN -> ~^[0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]$~
TNTNTNTN -> ~^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$~
TTTTNNNNN -> ~^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$~
TTNNTTTTTT -> ~^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$~
```